# Wired network connection fails after installing Ubuntu 12.04 

Tags: 12.04, networking, upgrade, dhcp

Having installed 12.04 amd64 desktop from the alternative ISO (I'm using LVM on a RAID5 array), my networking fails after booting into the installed system.

It works fine on the 12.04 Live CD and alternative desktop CD. It appears to bring up the interface correctly, but isn't finding anything on the other end.

`dhclient` says that it can't find a broadcasting interface (but works fine on the Live CD). My networking hardware is an Atheros AR8131 using the `atl1c` driver.

I've done nothing to the configuration since the installation.

The output from the commands listed below is in [**this pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/uSZc2j9c).

- `lshw -C network`
- `dhclient -v`
- `grep eth0 /var/log/syslog`

Comment: I'm confused (or maybe just clueless). I did not see any IPv4 addresses in your details. Is IPv4 enabled/working on your machine? Maybe it would help to add the output from `/sbin/ifconfig` and `/sbin/route`.

Answer (score 1):

After the next reboot (to be able to answer the above comment) the networking magically started working. Absolutely nothing changed between reboots. So... solved by pixies, I guess.